# Over riding tailwind classes

Tags: responsive-design, tailwind-css

Just recently started a project using tailwind for the very first time aiming to make 1 portfolio project. I didnt know that tailwind is by default set for mobile first so I designed Web site for desktop first and it looks great on 1500+px. However, I started working on a responsive design for a mobile phone and encountered a problem in adjusting layouts. I have a generic patern, because design is kind of REPETITIVE, class two-columns as a flex-box with 2 columns left and right which take 50% of parent width each. Now, for a mobile phone I want only 1 column with full with but I can not overide initial left and right class which I need for a big screen sizes. How to disable design or do something else for a small screens but again to have that class for big screen?

I set in tailwind.config screen layouts for different screen sizes and tried overiding claesses using sm:with-full and similar other settings but with none of succes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override tailwind classes.
Your have two option, the first one is to use media queries on css/scss file and apply proper class on different media-queries case.

The second option is to use Tailwind responsive design like follow :

```css
.yourclass {
    @apply w-full md:w-6/12 lg:w-4/12;
}
```

or in html

```html
<div class="w-full md:w-6/12 lg:w-4/12">
    <p>Your paragraph</p>
</div>
```

In each case, even if tailwind is mobile first (every project should be developped in mobile first), you just need to adapt the way your layout working to adjust on your needs.

See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design